# LaTeX creates some long lines (longer than 'linewidth')

Tags: formatting, latex

I am using texMaker to write a paper.
Latex sometimes doesn't send the last word of the line to the next line and hence, some lines become a little longer than the others. (it happened for about 10 lines in 10 pages).
I tried this command to avoid this problem:
\pretolerance=10000

however, this solution causes another problem. some lines become very short. For example, it leaves just a word (e.g. an "a") in one line and sends the rest to the next line.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, it sounds like you have a problem with hyphenation, leading to the common problem with an "overfull `hbox`" (the compiler log might say something about this).

This can e.g. occur when the language is incorrectly set so that the compiler cannot find reasonable places to hyphenate words. Instead it will try its best to work with character and word spacing to create reasonable lines, but sometimes it will just not be possible to yield good looking results. The compiler will issue the "overfull `hbox`"-warning so that the user is aware and can take action. The first thing is thus to make sure that the language is correctly identified.

Sometimes it might happen anyway, if one e.g. uses uncommon words or the lines for some reason are unusually cramped horizontally. If the hyphenation algorithm  fails, you can "help" it by adding hyphenation hints with `\-`, e.g. `hyphen\-ation`. This will normally be rendered as

```
hyphenation
```

but if the algorithm finds it favorable, it will perform a line break at that point as in:

```
The algorithm for hyphen-
ation in LaTeX is clever.
```

See also:

- [What does “overfull hbox” mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35/38804)
- [What is a “Overfull \hbox (9.89561pt too wide)”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111948/38804)
- [Overfull hbox - How do I fix this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36767/38804)

on the massively useful [TeX.SE network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks very much. your answer was so helpful. the word that generally causes this problem is the one that is not an English word; it is a 7-letter abbreviation word. So, I guess I have to use hyphenation hint. right?

Comment: @BaharS: Either the hint, or if you do not want it hyphenated, reword the sentence. The hyphenation algorithm in LaTeX is advanced and tries hard to work around these issues, so if it happens, it is for a reason. As a corollary, these kinds of rewordings are the very last thing one should do to avoid doubling the work in case one adds more information to the sentence anyway. If one is OK with hyphenation, the `\-` trick is alright. If the same word occurs in many places, one can add the hyphenation pattern once and for all with e.g. `\hyphenation{ex-em-pli-fy}, typically given in the preamble.

Comment: I can add that the situation where a line is not fully filled up is analogously called an "underfull `hbox`".